# facebook graph api logout url is not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook's graph api Version 3.1.1
It is working fine but the logout url is not working properly.

With the logout url it is being logged out from the facebook but it is not being logged out in my application. Strange but true.

I am pasting necessary snipet from the code.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt) {
                FB.ui({method: 'feed',
                    message: userPrompt,
                    link: hrefLink,
                    caption: hrefTitle,
                    picture: ''
                });
                //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
            }
            function publishStream() {
                streamPublish("Stream Publish", 'Checkout personalized products at www.picpixa.com. I found some of them are just awesome!', 'Checkout www.picpixa.com', 'http://www.picpixa.com', "Personalized Products");
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .box{
                margin: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #60729b;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                overflow:auto;
                background-color: #e6ebf8;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({
                appId: '',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true // parse XFBML
            });
        </script>

    <body>
        <div id="load" class="loader"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <?php 
                        echo "User: $user";
                        if (!$user) { ?>
                            <h1>You have to login using Facebook Login Button to see your uploaded images.</h1>
                            <a class='btn btn-primary' href="<?= $loginUrl ?>" onClick='loader()'><img src="Images/login.png"></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                                <a class='btn btn-primary' href="<?= $logoutUrl ?>" onClick='loader()'><img src="Images/logout.png"></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

basefacebook.php

```
public function getLogoutUrl($params = array()) {
        return $this->getUrl(
                        'www', 'logout.php', array_merge(array(
                    'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
                    'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
                                ), $params)
        );
    }
```

Feel free to ask for more info.
Please help me out with this.
Thank you,

Comment: anyone have the solution?

Comment: i tried to call the getLogoutUrl() function in the index.php in else part. Then added session_destroy() in the main function. Then remove function call from fbmain.php.
But it is not working properly.
Can anyone suggest me the solution as soon as possible?
It would be better if the problem solved without the use of session_destroy() because I am giving functionality to login in other social media also...